# how to update a raw within a partial view in MVC C#

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, controller, toad

i have a web application where i need to update the rows of a table one by one inside a partial view. the problem i'm facing now is how can i insert the update inside the partial view method in the controller. i'm using visual studio 2013 toad for oracle 
The partial view

```html
 <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th style="display:none;"> ProID </th>
                            <th> Requeser Name </th>
                            <th> Project Name </th>
                            <th> Supervisor Name </th>
                            
                            <th> Description </th>
                            <th> Start Date </th>
                            <th> Due Date </th>
                            <th> Status </th>
                            <th> Done </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (var items in Model)
                            {


                                <td>@items.USERID</td>
                            }
                            
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txt_pname" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txt_sname" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txt_dname" />
                            </td>
                    <td> <input name="text_stdate" id="iDate" class="form-control" readonly>
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                            </span></td>
                            <td>
                         <input name="text_dudate" id="iDate" class="form-control" readonly>
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                            </td>
                           <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txt_dname" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="txt_stat">
                                    <option>Pending</option>
                                    <option>Open</option>
                                    <option>Close</option>
                                    <option>Cancle</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

@foreach (var items in Model)
                            {
                    <td>
                        <a onclick="update_Row('@items.PROJECTT', '@items.IDP');" class="edit" href="#"> Done </a>
                    </td>
}
                      
                </table>

                <table class="" id="sample_editable_1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            
                            <th style="display:none;"> ProID </th>
                            <th> Requeser Name </th>
                            <th> Project Name </th>
                            <th> Supervisor Name </th>
                            
                            <th> Description </th>
                            <th> Start Date </th>
                            <th> Due Date </th>
                            <th> Status </th>
                            <th> Edit </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var items in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td style="display:none;"> @items.IDP</td>
                                <td>@items.USERID</td>
                                <td>@items.PROJECTT</td>
                                <td>@items.PROJSUP</td>
                                <td>@items.PROJDES</td>
                                <td>@items.STARTDT</td>
                                <td>@items.DUEDT</td>
                                <td>@items.SCONDITION</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="update_Row('@items.PROJECTT', '@items.IDP');" class="edit" href="#"> Edit </a>
                                </td>
                               
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

the controller

```html
 public ActionResult viewstat(string id)
        {



            List<mdlProject> itemList = new List<mdlProject>();
            try
            {
                dbconn.openConnection();

                strSQL = @"select ID,PROJTTL,PROJSVSOR,PROJDES,STARTDT,DUEDT,USERID,S_CONDITION from 
                 PR_TBLPROJECT 
                 inner join PR_TBLSTATUS on pr_tblstatus.s_id=PR_TBLPROJECT.id 
                 where PR_TBLPROJECT.id=:id";
                cmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, dbconn.DbConn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("PROJTTL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, id, ParameterDirection.Input);
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        itemList.Add(new mdlProject
                        {

                            PROJECTT = dr["PROJTTL"].ToString(),
                            PROJSUP = dr["PROJSVSOR"].ToString(),
                            PROJDES = dr["PROJDES"].ToString(),
                            STARTDT = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["STARTDT"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                            DUEDT = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DUEDT"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                            USERID = dr["USERID"].ToString(),
                            SCONDITION = dr["S_condition"].ToString(),
                            IDP = dr["ID"].ToString(),
                            //SID = dr["S_ID"].ToString(),
                            ACTV = "",
                        });
                    }

                }

               


                dr.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();

            }
            finally
            {


                dbconn.closeConnection();
            }
           


            return PartialView(itemList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exact error you are getting but approach will be On click of each anchor tag, call a javascript method and from that javascipt method send a ajax request to update the row and then call your partial view method `viewstat` to refresh the table.